# MySQL Select Query Too Slow \

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 90 data fields in it and 1500 records. When I do a Select query and try to pull entire table records it gets too slow. Even if I limit it to 100 records it takes more than 30 seconds.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

The query is as below:

```
SELECT 
  ID, FirstName, LastName, 
  date_format( InitialConsultDate , '%m/%d/%Y' ) AS InitialConsultDate, 
  Address1, Address2, City, State, Zip, HomeNumber, WorkNumber, CellNumber, Email, 
  Height, Weight, Age, Sex, Married, BirthDate, UnderPhysicianCare, MedicalIssue, 
  Smoking, Exercise, NumberTimesPerWeek, Dieting, AdequateWater, Cellulite, 
  BiggestConcern, CustomerDeal, LipoSessionsPurchased, FacialSessionsPurchased, 
  NutritionSessionsPurchased, ReferredBy, AdditionalNotes, WeightEvaluationDate1, 
  Weight1, WeightEvaluationDate2, Weight2, WeightEvaluationDate3, Weight3, BMI, 
  ClientBeforePictureFront, ClientAfterPictureFront1, ClientAfterPictureFront2, 
  ClientBeforePictureLeftSide, ClientAfterPictureLeftSide1, ClientAfterPictureLeftSide2, 
  ClientBeforePictureRightSide, ClientAfterPictureRightSide1, 
  ClientAfterPictureRightSide2, ClientMeasurementH1, ClientMeasurementH2, 
  ClientMeasurementH3, Area1Before, Area1After, Area2Before, Area2After, 
  Area3Before, Area3After, IsOldCustomer, ClientAfterFront3, ClientAfterFront4, 
  ClientAfterFront5, ClientAfterLeftSide3, ClientAfterLeftSide4, 
  ClientAfterLeftSide5, ClientAfterRightSide3, ClientAfterRightSide4, 
  ClientAfterRightSide5, ClientBeforeBack, ClientAfterBack1, ClientAfterBack2,
  ClientAfterBack3, ClientAfterBack4, ClientAfterBack5, Area1After1, Area1After2, 
  Area1After3, Area1After4, Area1After5, Area2After1, Area2After2, Area2After3, 
  Area2After4, Area2After5, Area3After1, Area3After2, Area3After3, Area3After4, 
  Area3After5 
FROM customer 
WHERE IsOldCustomer ='0' 
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: post schema also, use index

Comment: Please edit your question and include the query.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Are there indexes on `IsOldCustomer` and/or `ID`?

Comment: ID is the primary key and no index on IsOldCustomer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use indexes to optimise data search, something like:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_name ON your_table (field_name);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_name ON your_table (field_name);
```

- Use the first one for fields which have duplicated values (eg: date,
  name, etc..)
- Use the second one for fields which have uniques values
  (eg: login, id, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

To give you a heads up, follow the below suggestions:

1. A table with 90+ columns doesn't indicate a good database design [Although there can be exceptional cases]. Make your database more normalized.
2. Use Indexes (as suggested by other users) on columns present in your `WHERE` clause. Read all about [Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html).
3. Although this might not be a problem to look into now, if your data size potentially grows you might want to look into creating [PARTITION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html) for your Tables.

For now, of course, creating an index on `IsOldCustomer` column might just do the job.